# How to return the argument passed to a Mockito-mocked method in the thenReturn function?

Tags: java, mockito, java-10

This is what I want to achieve.

```
MyClass doSomething =  mock(MyClass.class);
when(doSomething.perform(firstParameter, any(Integer.class), any(File.class)))
    .thenReturn(firstParameter);
```

Basically I want the mocked class's method to always return the first argument that was passed into the method.

I have tried to use `ArgumentCaptor`, like so

```
ArgumentCaptor<File> inFileCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(File.class);
MyClass doSomething = mock(MyClass.class);
when(doSomething.perform(inFileCaptor.capture(), any(Integer.class), any(File.class)))
    .thenReturn(firstParameter);
```

But `mockito` just failed with this error message:

```
No argument value was captured!
You might have forgotten to use argument.capture() in verify()...
...or you used capture() in stubbing but stubbed method was not called.
Be aware that it is recommended to use capture() only with verify()

Examples of correct argument capturing:
    ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
    verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
    assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```

I think the `ArgumentCaptor` class only works with `verify` calls.

So how can I return the first parameter as passed-in during test?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do this usually with `thenAnswer`:

```java
when(doSomething.perform(firstParameter, any(Integer.class), 
             any(File.class)))
    .thenAnswer(new Answer<File>() {
          public File answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        return invocation.getArgument(0);
    }
 };
```

and you can simplify this to be

```java
when(doSomething.perform(firstParameter, any(Integer.class), any(File.class)))
  .thenAnswer(invocation -> invocation.getArgument(0));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I am using version `2.23.0` and it seems the APIs are slight different form your example. e.g. For me it is `getArgument(index)` instead of `getArgumentAt(index, class)`

Answer (score 6):

You can also do with `org.mockito.AdditionalAnswers`

```
when(doSomething.perform(eq(firstParameter), any(Integer.class), any(File.class)))
    .thenAnswer(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg())
```

Also @Fred solution could be written with lambda

```
when(doSomething.perform(eq(firstParameter), any(Integer.class), any(File.class)))
        .thenAnswer(i->i.getArgument(0));
```